# Why $\{0, 1, -1\}$ is not a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

People always say there is no non trivial finite subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ since all subgroups have the form $n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\in \mathbb N$. I was wondering why $\{0, 1, -1\}$ is not a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$?

Comment: In general, every subgroup takes the form of $n \mathbb{Z}$ because you need closure. If $a$ is in your subgroup, then so is $a + a = 2a, a + 2a = 3a, \ldots$, as well as $-a, -a + (-a) = -2a, -a + (-2a) = -3a, \ldots$.

Comment: *Why* do people downvote these kinds of questions? It is a clear question that is formatted well (and even with good tags)!

Comment: @Lovsovs: probably because the answer is trivial by the definition of subgroup. $1+1\not\in\{0,1,-1\}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yeah, but even though people miss trivialities, should they be downvoted? I guess this is an answer for meta..

Comment: @Lovsovs: that is a delicate question. MSE is designed for math at all levels, but too many trivial questions are not a good thing for quality standards. In general, I am glad to accept simple questions, but there is a boundary, and my personal opinion is that this particular question is a bit off. I did not downvote, anyway.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yeah, I guess you're right, thanks for giving some context (to the downvote)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $1 + 1$ is not an element of $\left \{ 0, 1, -1 \right \}$.
Maybe you got confused and wanted the composition operation to be multiplication. But for $\left \{ 0, 1, -1 \right \}$ to be a subgroup, it has to have the same operation as in $\left ( \mathbb{Z}, + \right )$ ie. addition.

Comment: I see, I forgot group operation is on $G\times G$ so that it can take the same element.

Answer (score 4):

Closure. Notice that $1 \in \{0, 1, -1\}$ but $1+1 = 2 \notin \{0, 1, -1 \}$.

Answer (score 3):

The set $\{0,1,-1\}$ is not a group because
$$1+1\notin\{0,1,-1\}$$